# How to handle SOAP request Payload and send a SOAP response XML in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, http, soap

I have a SOAP web service written in C# that can handle SOAP request and Respond accordingly using SOAP Action and ReplyAction Headers.

```
[OperationContract(Action = "http://www.example.com/schemas/xxxx/xxxx/service/authenticationagent/2013/03/01/IAuthenticationAgentService/GetPostPromptResult", ReplyAction = "http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/OXPd/service/authenticationagent/2013/03/01/IAuthenticationAgentService/GetPostPromptResult")]
            [XmlSerializerFormat]
            PostPromptResult GetPostPromptResult(string authenticationContextId, string languageCode, string serverContextId);
```

I need to implement the same web service using Javascript and serve it using node js server.

I was able to handle REST web service request and response since they have a URI to hit.

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/PostPromptAuthentication", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        [XmlSerializerFormat]
        AuthenticationResult GetPostPromptResult(AuthenticationRequest postPromptQuery);
```

And in node js server I can do this,

```
 if (request.url.match('PostPromptAuthentication')) {
                    var data = fs.readFileSync('PostPromptAuthentication.xml', 'utf-8');
                    if(!validationResult)
                    {
                        data = data.replace('succeeded','failed');
                    }
                    response.writeHead(200);
                    response.end(data);
```

For SOAP, I dont have an URI to hit. I only have request and response XML payloads which have SOAP Action and Reply Action in their headers.

How do I handle these SOAP requests in node js?

Is there something like

```
 request.SOAPAction.match('') in javascript?
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.